# Apache RewriteRule index.php with date

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have items like the following:

```
index.php/2013-11-12-00-12-30/max-600
```

That I need to redirect to the following:

```
/products/max-600
```

I'm using the following and it's not working. What am I missing? Other redirects are working fine so I know the engine is on, etc.

```
RewriteRule \/index\.php\/2013\-11\-12\-00\-12\-30\/(.*)$ /products/$1
```